# Tool to run same sql query on multiple Oracle Servers and Aggregate Result

Tags: sql, database, oracle, multi-tenant

I am looking for a database client tool that can allow me to run same query on multiple identical databases on many servers.

We have 100+ servers that each server has some custom data that needs to be pulled and aggregated from same tables (shards) in multiple servers.

I want to be able to run a query like this

```
select COL1,COL2 from MY_TABLE
```

This query will return me one or more rows. All these need to aggregate in one table.

Any tools that are standalone or web based or opensource or licensed Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My open source program [Method5](https://method5.github.io/) was built for tasks like this.

The program runs on an Oracle server and can be called by any SQL client like this:

```
select * from table(m5('select COL1,COL2 from MY_TABLE'));
```

It returns the columns requested as well as an additional column named `DATABASE_NAME`.  It gathers the data in parallel, handles exceptions, and stores the data in a table.

There is an optional second parameter that lets you specify a list of targets.  By default Method5 queries all configured databases but you can limit the results like this:

```
select * from table(m5('select COL1,COL2 from MY_TABLE', 'dev,test,acme%,db1234'));
```

There's also a procedure, M5_PROC, that gives you more control over things like which table to store the results in and whether to run asynchronously.  In practice, you
 might find it quite tricky to reliably query hundreds of databases.  It's not uncommon for a small number of databases to be unavailable for reasons out of your control.  That can be difficult, but Method5 gives you the ability to handle those situations.

In some ways Method5 is a packaged version of @miracle173's answer.  If you just need a one-time query, it's probably best to go with his solution.  But if you need something more robust, that will be called frequently, and needs to handle any code you throw at it, then it would be worth the time to install and configure Method5.  And if you need any help installing or configuring it you can contact me directly.

Comment: Thanks - does this require you to be admin and be installed on the database ? Can it do it remotely?

Comment: @software.wikipedia The program must be installed and configured by a DBA on one master database.  And there's a small one-time script that must be run on the 100 remote databases to create the user.  That remote script must be run as SYSDBA, you may be able to run it remotely depending on how REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE is set on each database.  The program was designed for DBAs but there are ways to allow other users to access it, see [the user guide for details](https://method5.github.io/user_guide/#services_for_non_dbas).  (I need to fix a link on that page, I'll do that soon.)

Comment: Thanks for the details. It helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Oracle database and create database links to the databases on your servers. You need one database link for each database. Then you can run the following query.

```
select COL1,COL2 
  from MY_TABLE@db1
union all
select COL1,COL2 
  from MY_TABLE@db2
union all
select COL1,COL2 
  from MY_TABLE@db3
union all
select COL1,COL2 
  from MY_TABLE@db4
```

This database must be created on a server from wich the other databaes can be reached, it can be an arbitrary database, e.g.  an Oracle  Database Express Edition. Express Edition doesn't cost anything.

Another posibility is to use an MS Access Database- For a table in a remote database you can create a table in the Access database that is connected to the remote table. I used  this approach some times but  at the moment I don't remember more details.

I would prefer the Oracle solution. You can create a view that contains the above select. You can use Oracle SQL to query the view.

.

Comment: Thanks - this is a good option - however installing on the actual database and adding DB links will require admin privilege (that I don't have as application developer/DevOps engineer). Also, it can be too many dblinks. I am looking for something that can run remotely and connect to each DB separately.